# Why Power Automate do not run my script?

Tags: microsoft-excel, script, office365, microsoft-power-automate-desktop

I use Power Automate (not desktop version). My flow seems simple:

1. Every weeks
2. Copy file (From folder A to folder B in the same SharePoint). Replace existing file.
3. Run a script in the file (removes duplicated emails and removes
   columns)

Only Copy file works.
I tried to split the script in two: First script removes duplicated emails. Second script removes column. No success.

Here is the first script:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
// Remove duplicates from range A:AF on selectedSheet
selectedSheet.getRange("A:AF").removeDuplicates([10], false);
}
```

Here is the second script:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
// Delete range B:F on selectedSheet
selectedSheet.getRange("B:F").delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.left);
// Delete range G:G on selectedSheet
selectedSheet.getRange("G:G").delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.left);
// Delete range H:L on selectedSheet
selectedSheet.getRange("H:L").delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.left);
// Delete range K:Q on selectedSheet
selectedSheet.getRange("K:Q").delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.left);
// Delete range M:N on selectedSheet
selectedSheet.getRange("M:N").delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.left);
}
```

Have you any recommendation using Power Automate online or the desktop version?

Comment: I don't believe VBA is supported for online files. I believe Microsoft began releasing Office Scripts that do support scripts for online. I don't know what configuration issues you may encounter...

Comment: @gns100 : I've seen tutos doing almost the same flow and the script runned. Do you think it will better work with the desktop version?

Comment: As with everything, there are pros/cons, PA desktop should be able to run your scripts, but will only run if the deployed machine is turned on (and possibly signed in). In the end trying to find the right balance between high coding (VBA) vs low coding (PA) is dependent on your comfort level. It is something I am still trying to figure out...